# oAuth with Elastic Load Balancer SSL

Tags: oauth, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I am using AWS EC2 instances with ELB. I know that ELB itself has SSL connection enabled. My EC2 instances does not support SSL.

Here comes my problem. I need to implement some kind of authentication method like oAuth.

Is there a way to authenticate users with ELB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that on ELB.

I recommend you to take a look at the ELB documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/Welcome.html and this blog post http://harish11g.blogspot.com.br/2012/03/ssl-offloading-elastic-load-balancing.html

Answer (score 0):

In Kong, you can do one thing. You can terminate SSL (trusted, can use free SSL via ACM) on ELB of KONG and use the feature `Accept HTTP if already terminated` in OAUTH2 plugin. But keep in mind the ELB Listeners will be (Secure TCP 443)--> (Secure TCP 8443 [https port exposed by KONG]).